# In React Native, why does this not work? I just want to save and use these two valuse in a local storage, but one works, but the other doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, storage, local

Just like the title says, I want to save two values into a local storage with AsyncStorage.
My app is quite simple.
There are two buttons that increment each of the numbers by pressing them.
They're put in setState.
I save them into the local storage, and want to use them for when the user closes/re-visit my app.

[image: My app preview]

I successfully made it work for one value, but not for the other value, even though I beleve they're structured in the same way like the codes below.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from "react-native";

import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";



const Home = () => {

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const [counter2, setCounter2] = useState(0);
 
  //For getting values that are saved into the local storage.
  const get = async () => {
    const values = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(["@count", "@count2"]);

    values.forEach((value) => {
      if (value[0] === "@count") {
        const savedcount = parseInt(value[1]) || 0;
        setCounter(savedcount);
        console.log(savedcount); // 6 or any number
      }
      if (value[0] === "@count2") {
        const savedcount2 = parseInt(value[1]) || 0;
        setCounter2(savedcount2);
        console.log(savedcount2); //[Function bound dispatchSetState]

      }    
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    get();
  }, []);


  const increment = async () => {
    setCounter((pre) => pre + 1);
  };

  const increment2 = async () => {
    setCounter2((pre) => pre + 1);
  };

  //For saving those states.
  const saving = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("@count", counter.toString());
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("@count2", counter2.toString());
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    saving();
  }, [counter, counter2]);


  const clearAll = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.clear();
    } catch (e) {
      // clear error
    }

    console.log("Done.");
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{counter}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{counter2}</Text>

      <Button title="count up" onPress={increment} />
      <Button title="count up2" onPress={increment2} />
      <Button title="All clear" onPress={clearAll} />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    flex: 1,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 50,
  },
});

export default Home;
```

In the end, `counter` is successfully saved and used, but `counter2` isn't, even tho they're structured in the same way I beleve.

I need some help. It'd be nice if someone fixes my codes to make them work.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why does your `useEffect` have `increment*` functions as a dependency instead of `counter*`? It will run every render now instead of when variables change

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I will edit this post to reflect that!

Comment: Do you get the `rendering` in the logs?

Comment: Yep, this time I see the log when the first render and  visiting the page Home. However the entire situation still remains almost the same unfortunately

Comment: Try logging `savedcount2` as well so we can check if it's saved

Comment: Oh now I get this: ```console.log(savedcount2); //[Function bound dispatchSetState]```

Comment: I run your code and it seems like you probably made a mistake before and stored a function in the storage. Try clearing the storage and it should work fine

Comment: Oh really? I will try! Honestly, This is almost my first time trying to make use of a local storage, so yeah I most likey made something wrong

Comment: I casted a spell that clear all the data, and now everything went wrong...could you please try that too? I put the magical button in the post

Comment: Try replacing `parseInt(value[1])` with `parseInt(value[1]) || 0`

Comment: Thank you for the helps kindly! Now everything went back to normal! However, the situation still remains the same...one works, the other doesn't...this is a bit too tricky for me, what I made wrong

Comment: After refreshing the page, are those two values still there unchanged?